# Possible to get a bash script to accept input from terminal if its stdin has been redirected?

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal

Say I've got a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Gimme some stuff: " stuff
echo "**${stuff}**"
```

If the script is invoked with something piping into it, such as:

```
echo "Here's some stuff" | ./myscript.bash
```

Then the `read` command will read from the pipe. Even if I try to [clear stdin out](https://superuser.com/questions/276531/clear-stdin-before-reading) before I hit that `read` command, it will still return immediately.

Is there any way around that? If I don't have any control of the way in which my script is invoked, is there any way to force it to accept input for a `read` or `select` from the terminal? If not, are there any sneakier ways to pause the script to get input from a user other than from stdin?

Comment: This is such a wonderfully worded question! It was still very difficult to find because any search matching `/bash .* (read|accept|pipe) .* (stdin|tty)/` favors simple questions about how to pipe into a bash script. I'm so glad you managed to break through the algorithm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.  The terminal is always `/dev/tty`.  All that is necessary is to have `read` get its input from the terminal rather than stdin:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Gimme some stuff: " stuff </dev/tty
echo "**${stuff}**"
```

In operation, this looks like:

```
$ echo asdfdsaf | read.sh
Gimme some stuff: 123
**123**
```

#### A slightly more complex way of doing the same thing

Here we open `/dev/tty` as file descriptor 3.  The option `-u 3` tells `read` to use file descriptor 3:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tty
read -u 3 -p "Gimme some stuff: " stuff
echo "**${stuff}**"
```

Comment: /dev/ttty works on Linux. Does it also work on other Unix systems, e.g. macOS?