# Is there a `read -n` equivalent command for Bourne shell?

Tags: linux, sh, input

Is there a way to make my script wait for the user to press any key and then continue without them having to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>? I want to make it work in Bourne shell (`sh`), not Bash.

Comment: see also [Can I read a single character from stdin in POSIX shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464930/can-i-read-a-single-character-from-stdin-in-posix-shell)

Answer (score 2):

#### Preliminary notes

Nowadays `sh` is [not necessarily the legacy Bourne shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98912/108618). Nowadays `sh` is a shell that supports *at least* the features required by POSIX (assuming a correct implementation). POSIX specifies the [`sh` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) and the [Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/shell.html).

I assume you want your code to work in a POSIX shell and to be portable in general.

---

#### Issues

[`dd ibs=1 count=…` is a POSIX way to read an exact number of bytes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278465/108618). It seems to be the only portable command line utility that can do the job reliably. But `dd` reads bytes, while `read -n` in Bash reads *characters*. [POSIX allows multi-byte characters in locales other than `POSIX`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap06.html#tag_06_02). Even if you run the entire script with `LC_ALL=POSIX`, the terminal (terminal emulator) may still generate a multi-byte sequence upon some single keystroke. Such sequence may not be a multi-byte character; it may be an escape sequence ([e.g. for <kbd>F1</kbd>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/211923/108618), also see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116630/108618)).

After you read just one byte, the rest will remain and it will be read by anything that tries to read from the terminal later (it may be a part of your script or the interactive shell you run the script from).

Additionally if you run sole `dd ibs=1 count=1` then you will most likely discover that nothing gets to `dd` until you exceed [`{MAX_INPUT}` or `{MAX_CANON}`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_05), or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110248/108618) (and in case of `count` being more than `1`, if you want to provide less bytes then you may need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21261742/10765659)).

To deal with these issues you need the [non-canonical mode](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_07). Use [`stty -icanon`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html). In general starting with `stty raw` looks like a good idea.

---

#### Code

The following example is a proof of concept. Because it manipulates line settings of the terminal and reads from the terminal **you *must not* paste it into an interactive shell, this won't work**. Paste it into a file and run the file.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "Press any key to continue."

saveterm="$(stty -g)"                     # save terminal state
stty raw
stty -echo -icanon min 1 time 0           # prepare to read one byte
dd ibs=1 count=1 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null   # read one byte
stty -icanon min 0 time 0                 # prepare to read lefotvers
while read none; do :; done               # read leftovers
stty "$saveterm"                          # restore terminal state
```

---

#### Notes

- The script doesn't check if its stdin is a terminal, but in general it should ([`[ -t 0 ]`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401938/108618)).
- In a sane setup a modifier key (e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>), when pressed alone, sends no input to whatever reads from the terminal; therefore our code will not register such key as "any key".
- The "read leftovers" trick is taken from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1268886/432690).
- Thanks to `stty raw` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> can be "any key" as well, instead of sending `SIGINT` or `SIGSTOP` respectively. Still the shell interpreting the script may get a signal from elsewhere, so in general it may happen it exits before it gets to `stty "$saveterm"`; so it may happen it leaves the terminal in a state not suitable for interactive use. You may want to trap relevant signals and restore the initial state of the terminal anyway.
- <strike>It's true [one should double-quote variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) in general. Here `$saveterm` is deliberately not quoted because `stty -g` generates output that is unspecified. Implementations of `stty` are allowed to generate output with spaces and later expect the shell to split it and pass multiple arguments. What is specified is a constraint that the output of `stty -g` must be safe when unquoted, it must not trigger word expansion in a shell. For portability unquoted `$saveterm` is better.</strike>

  Edit: [that was a defect in the POSIX specification](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1532). The above code has been fixed.
- To know what byte was read you need to save the output of `dd`, either to a regular file (`>some_file`) that you will examine later, or to a variable (`variable="$(dd …)"`). But:

  - A terminal is able to generate a null byte (commonly with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd>) but most (all?) implementations of `sh` cannot store a null byte in a variable. Storing in a file is OK, if only you can examine/manipulate its content without reading it into a variable.
  - `dd` from the above code will give you only one byte, it may not be enough to tell the character or the key. OTOH a single byte should be enough to tell apart e.g. <kbd>Q</kbd> from anything else, so `Press Q to quit or any other key to continue.` or `P - proceed; B - back; Q - quit; H - help` seem possible to implement without analyzing more bytes.

---

#### What about more bytes?

The above should be fine for "press any key". A real equivalent of `read -n` should read one byte at a time and decode the sequence until it gets the desired number of *characters*. I'm not going to try to build it here.